# как грамотно отобразить текст веденный в input в html

Tags: javascript, html

Подскажите пожалуйста

```js
function calc() {
  // Стоимость лота, $
  let lot = document.querySelector(".lot").value;
  lot.innerText = lot.append(lot);
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="lot" value="" onchange="calc()" placeholder="1000" /> <br><br>
<div >Стоимость лота<span class="lot1">0</span></div><br>
```

нужно чтобы lot.value отображалось в span .lot1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Но сработает при выходе из инпута. А append в данном случае вообще не работает у вас.

```js
function calc() {
  // Стоимость лота, $
  let lot = document.querySelector(".lot").value;
  let lot1 = document.querySelector(".lot1");
  lot1.innerText = lot;
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="lot" value="" onchange="calc()" placeholder="1000" /> <br><br>
<div >Стоимость лота: <span class="lot1">0</span></div><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

А если `onchange` заменить на `oninput`, то будет работать в процессе набора

```js
function calc() {
  // Стоимость лота, $
  let lot = document.querySelector(".lot").value;
  let lot1 = document.querySelector(".lot1");
  lot1.innerText = lot;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="lot" value="" oninput="calc()" placeholder="1000" /> <br><br>
<div >Стоимость лота: <span class="lot1">0</span></div><br>
```